# JavaScript: how to render a border around each line item from innerHTML

Tags: javascript

I have some JavaScript that renders line-item details of some orders.  Here is a code snippet:

```
  fetch(`/orders/${businessUnit}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(orders=> {

  // create a Div for each order
  orders.forEach(order => {
    const element = document.createElement('div');
    element.innerHTML = `
                  <span class="buyer" col-3"> ${order.buyer} </span>
                  <span class="seller" col-3"> ${order.seller} </span>
                  <span class="timestamp" col-3"> ${order.timestamp} </span>
              `
}
```

How would I render a border around each line item `order`?

Thanks in advance.

############

**EDIT**

Following the advice of @Anton Neverov, I have the following:

```
  emails.forEach(order=> {
    const element = document.createElement('div');
    element.classList.add('border-class')
    element.style.padding = '5px';
    element.innerHTML = `
                  <div class='border-class'>
                  <span> ${order.buyer} </span>
                  <span> ${order.seller} </span>
                  <span> ${order.timestamp} </span>
                  </div>
              `
```

**CSS**

```
.border-class {
    border: 1px solid black
}
```

The border does not seem to be rendering.  What did I miss here?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anton's answer is valid.

I've created a live working snippet here:

```js
var emails = [1,2,3,4,5];

emails.forEach(order=> {
    const element = document.createElement('div');
    element.style.padding = '5px';
    element.innerHTML = `
                  <div class='border-class'>
                  <span>Buyer: ${order.buyer} </span>
                  <span>Seller: ${order.seller} </span>
                  <span>Timestamp: ${order.timestamp} </span>
                  </div>
                  `
    const parentContainer = document.getElementById("parent-container");
    parentContainer.appendChild(element);
});
```

```css
.border-class{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent-container"></div>
```

And you can see it on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/rapaccinim/pen/wvdJREV) too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add border css rules to every div.
Somthing like:

```
orders.forEach(order => {
  const element = document.createElement('div');
  element.style.border = '1px solid black';
  element.innerHTML = `
    <span class="buyer col-3"> ${order.buyer} </span>
    <span class="seller col-3"> ${order.seller} </span>
    <span class="timestamp col-3"> ${order.timestamp} </span>
  `
}
```

Also, you can create a new class in CSS and add this class to order's div:

```
element.classList.add('border-class');
```